# How can I convert tensor in TF 2.x to Numpy?

Tags: numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0, metrics, tensor

How can I convert a tensor to Numpy without using TF 1.0 combability, Session or run_eagerly=True? I am trying to manipulate y_pred tensor in custom metrics in Keras.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.numpy()` on your tensor. Have a look here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics